# Find $f'(z)$ of the following $f(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

There are 2 problems that I solved simply, but was wondering if there is a deeper concept that I may be missing. Whenever something seems too simple, I worry that I missed something. We are learning about Cauchy-Riemann in class, could those equations be used here in some way?

**Problem 1**:

$$f(z)=\frac{(z^2+1)}{(z^3-4z+5)}$$

**My solution to problem 1**:

$$f'(z)=\frac{-z^4-7z^2+10z+4}{(z^3-4z+5)^2}$$

---

**Problem 2**:

$$f(z)=e^{z^2}$$

**My solution to problem 2**:

$$f'(z)=2ze^{z^2}$$

Comment: Thiings differentiate pretty much as expected. But beware of the log function.  Its a sticky affair.

Comment: @ncmathsadist even for complex numbers? I think we are supposed to interpret $z$ as $x+iy$ here...not sure though...

Comment: All polynomials, the circular functoions and the exponential all differentiate exactly as you would expect.

Comment: The chain rule works too.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!!

Comment: The rules for derivatives of sums, products, quotients, and the chain rule, for real calculus , apply to complex calculus also. And the functions sin(x),cos (x) and exp(x) extend to the complex domain, with the same formulas for their derivatives.